# How can I handle the error "Error: all(lengths == 1L | lengths == n) is not TRUE"?

Tags: r, error-handling, google-sheets, r-googlesheets

I have been trying to solve this problem, but with no success. Imagine I have a google worksheet called "database". In this worksheet I have a sheet called "Sheet1". And in this sheet I have a table (that starts from A1) with column names "a1", "a2", "a3".

Now, I want to append a new row with values "12", "23", "34". For this I input this code:

```
library(googlesheets)

worksheet <- gs_title("database")
gs_add_row(ss=worksheet, ws="Sheet1", input = c("12","23","34"))
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Input is too long. Only first 0 elements will be used.
Error: all(lengths == 1L | lengths == n) is not TRUE
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gs_add_rows only can add rows once the header is available in the google sheet so you need to create the first row or the header information with gs_edit_cells() before you use add_rows.

This is explained in the [googlesheets vignette.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/vignettes/basic-usage.html#edit-cells)

[Here is a screenshot of the appropriate code from the Vignette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXKx7.png)

Comment: It seems more than just the header is necessary, I had to add the header **AND** one row before this error disappeared.